# Explanation of code - fork, wait, execv

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait

I'm trying to understand what the following code does:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int pid;

    for(;;) {
        pid = fork();
        printf(getpid());

        if(pid == -1) {
            printf("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0) {
            execv("MYFORKAPP", NULL);
            exit(2);
        }

        wait();
    }
return 0;
}
```

The program itself is called `MYFORKAPP`. I'm learning about these 3 functions and I saw this code on the internet and I don't understand what it does.

I tried to run it (Fedora GCC) but the terminal is empty.

Should it at-least print the first `getpid()`?

Can you please explain me this code?

Comment: It looks like a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Comment: @leeduhem, parent process waits (blocking call) the child process. In other words, parent process doen't have more then one child process.

Comment: @someuser That child process will execuate the same program again, and it will `fork()` then `wait()`, and its child will do the same thing again, and so on. Not a normal fork bomb, yes, but it still will create lots of process until it cannot.

Comment: @leeduhem, if "MYFORKAPP" is a same program then yes, it's a fork bomb. :)

Comment: for see more about your OS proccessing, please use `ps axf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf(getpid());
```

This may crash the program. `printf()` expects its first argument be a string, but `getpid()` will return a integer, so this integer will be used as a pointer to an array of character, this very likely leads to a crash, i.e. segmentation fault.

Besides that, what this program does is

1. `fork()` a child process and `wait()`
2. this child process will execuate the same program again
3. so it will `fork()` and `wait()`
4. and so on, until your system does not have enough resource to create new process
5. then `fork()` will fail, these different level child processes will exit one by one
6. finally, the first process created by your shell will exit, and the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

What the following code does - segmentation fault. 
Must be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int pid;

    for(;;) {
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1) {
            printf("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0) {
            printf("child has pid %d\n", getpid());
            execv("MYFORKAPP", NULL);
            exit(2);
        }

        wait();
    }
return 0;
}
```

This is a loop:
1. Parent creates a child process. 
2. Child turnes to MYFORKAPP.
3. Parent wait for the child process.
4. Child terminates (may be).
5. goto 1